# SOLR AND clause in q object

Tags: solr

I need to query SOLR index using a WHERE clause -

When I try with AND clause its not working

```
NOT WORKING
category:2  AND -document_type:category 

WORKING
category:2 -document_type:category
```

Which is the correct syntax?

Comment: .. both work here. What kind of issue are you seeing with the first?

Comment: Both work here as well.. Do you get different number of results?

Comment: It works for me as well..Not sure if I had something earlier...Thanks much..I will close this...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass -(document_type:category) as a filter query (fq=-(document_type:category)). Should work that way and is also faster because of optimized caches on filter queries.

Also tested your specific case, but it also works for me in a regular query.